# How to make a banner always appear at the bottom of a screen, on load?

Tags: html, css

For my personal website I'm trying to have a banner with my name appear at the bottom of the screen on load no matter its size.

I don't want the banner to follow the screen though.

Here is the banner CSS/HTML that I'm working with:

```css
.header-card {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 20%;
    margin: auto;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-card">
        <h1>My Name</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

At the bottom of your browser window:

```
.header-card {
    position: fixed; //fixed is absolute to a browser
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: white;
}

<div class="header-card">
    <h1>My Name</h1>
</div>
```

At the bottom of your page (or parented "relative" element):

```
.header-card {
    position: absolute; // absolute is absolute to a relative element
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: white;
}

<div class="header-card">
    <h1>My Name</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you put the div in your header? Cuz the CSS class is called header-card.

Comment: I just used the example from question. But it would work with header too if parent header is not relative.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for `position:fixed`, which will cause your element to "stick" to the bottom of your page :

```
.header-card {
   position: fixed;
   /* other styles omitted for brevity */
}
```

If you only wanted the ad to appear on the initial page load and to disappear when the user began scrolling, you could accomplish this with a little snippet of Javascript using the `onscroll` event :

```
<!-- This will hide your ad when any scrolling occurs -->
<body onscroll="ad.style.display = 'none';">
<div id='ad' class="header-card">
   <h1>My Name</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually don't want it to "stick" to the page. I only want it to show up at the bottom of the screen when the user loads the page.

*Issue is different sized screens

Comment: So you want it to appear at the bottom and to disappear when the user begins scrolling?

Comment: To generate at the bottom of the screen and then stay in that spot after the user starts to scroll. Does that make sense?

I'll try working with that JS you showed

Comment: So you want it to appear at the bottom and then just stay at that specific position (i.e. not the bottom)? Doing that seems like it could cause some difficulties with it overlapping certain content on different viewports. Using `position:fixed` would stick to the bottom, but if that doesn't work, you might be better off simply placing the banner at a certain location and just using normal relative positioning.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.header-card {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 20%;
    margin: auto;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: white;
}

.banner {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="header-card">
        <h1>My Name</h1>
</div>
<div class="banner">banner</div>
```